# Is there a way to get svg path from svg url?? (not from svg file)

Tags: javascript, html, svg

```js
console.clear();

/* SETUP */
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  5000
);
camera.position.z = 500;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 2 : 1);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

/* CONTROLS */
const controlsWebGL = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

/* PARTICLES */
// Get the Path in the DOM
const path = document.querySelector("path");
// Store the total length of the path
const length = path.getTotalLength();

// Empty array to store all vertices
const vertices = [];
// Loop along the path
for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 0.2) {
  // Get the coordinates of a point based on the index value
  const point = path.getPointAtLength(i);
  // Create a new vector at the coordinates
  const vector = new THREE.Vector3(point.x, -point.y, 0);
  // Randomize a little bit the point to make the heart fluffier
  vector.x += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 30;
  vector.y += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 30;
  vector.z += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 70;
  // Push the vector into the array
  vertices.push(vector);
}
// Create a new geometry from the vertices
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(vertices);
// Define a pink material
const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
  color: 0xee5282,
  blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
  size: 3
});
// Create a Points mesh based on the geometry and material
const particles = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
// Offset the particles in the scene based on the viewbox values
particles.position.x -= 600 / 2;
particles.position.y += 552 / 2;
// Add the particles in to the scene
scene.add(particles);

/* Animate the scene rotation */
gsap.fromTo(scene.rotation, {
  y: -0.3
}, {
  y: 0.3,
  repeat: -1,
  yoyo: true,
  ease: 'power2.inOut',
  duration: 3
});

/* RENDERING */
function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

/* EVENTS */
function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.136.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.136.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.co/gsap@3/dist/gsap.min.js"></script>
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 552">
  <path d="M300,107.77C284.68,55.67,239.76,0,162.31,0,64.83,0,0,82.08,0,171.71c0,.48,0,.95,0,1.43-.52,19.5,0,217.94,299.87,379.69v0l0,0,.05,0,0,0,0,0v0C600,391.08,600.48,192.64,600,173.14c0-.48,0-.95,0-1.43C600,82.08,535.17,0,437.69,0,360.24,0,315.32,55.67,300,107.77" fill="#ee5282"/>
</svg>
```

First of all, This example is using three.js and svg that I want to implement.
The question has nothing to do with three.js, so you don't have to look at the example or just look at the question below.

The problem is that in the above example, it appears that the path.getPointAtLength was used directly for the svg path of html.
In my case, it is not an svg file, but I always get a different svg url from API.

It was successful to set the svg url in img.src and display svg img on the canvas.
But, I don't know how to implement the codepen example above.

I don't know how to use my svg url for this part...T.T
Please help me...

```
// Get the Path in the DOM
const path = document.querySelector("path");

// Store the total length of the path const
length = path.getTotalLength();
```

Comment: You _will_ need to load the SVG, probably with `fetch`, then turn it into text, then use a `DOMParser` to turn it into a domElement, attach it to the document (necessary or it won't calculate properly!) then select the `path`. You cannot do this from _just_ the URL.

Comment: @somethinghere I can get svgPaths from THREE.svgloader. It has the following structure.
`  const loader = new SVGLoader();
  let svgPaths;
  let updateMap = [];

  try {
    svgPaths = await loader.loadAsync(svgUrl, (data) => {
      return data.paths;
      // console.log("svgPaths", svgPaths);
    });
  } catch(err) {

  }
  console.log(, svgPaths.paths);

  svgPaths.paths.forEach((path, i) => {
    const shapes = path.toShapes(true);

    shapes.forEach((shape, j) => {});

Comment: can i use this? How can I convert svg to text?

Comment: I presume THREE returns it as THREE Shapes, which have a slightly different interface. To get the svg, use `const svg = await fetch( url ).then(response => response.text()).then(text => new DOMParser().parseFromString( text, 'image/svg+xml' ).querySelectorAll( 'svg' )`, then attach it to the document (required to make the calculations work, which the THREEJS loader probably doesn't have to) `document.body.append( svg )`, then select your path `const path = svg.querySelector('path')`. You can then use the `SVGGeometryElement` interface methods you mentioned.

Comment: @somethinghere wow..wow...........it works..........Thank you very much!! I've been searching for this all day. Thank you very much...T.T You're so kind and nice.....! Have a good day!!!!